# Missing HD space OSX. I have emptied the trash (of course)

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

I have an external HD called "Macintosh HD". It use to be my main drive and has since became my backup. I deleted some music from Macintosh HD (about 20GB worth) which went into the trash. Then with my external HD unmounted, I tried to delete the items in trash. Obviously it didn't work since my external HD was unmounted. Instead of putting 2+2 together, I immediately used an application called "trash it" to delete whatever was in my trash. The "trash it" application immediately emptied the trash but I notice that the free space isn't showing up on my external HD.

I tried to delete the .trashes and .trash file on the HD to no avail. When I used "Omnidisksweeper" I see the discrepancy in free space vs total space. (screenshot attached). I am not sure what to do!!! Where are those files in Limbo?

Here is a screenshot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/igMZV.jpg

Comment: @SteveJorgensen: Not **also**. *Instead* is more appropriate; cross-posting is discouraged here, so posting the same question on multiple sites is a violation of guidelines.

Comment: @KenWhite: Thanks for that. BTW, this item was apparently moved from SO? I didn't know there was a way to do that.

Comment: @SteveJorgensen: Yes; moderators can move posts between sites, and when close votes are cast for off-topic questions you can suggest migrating to (certain) other sites. You can also flag the question for moderator attention with a suggestion for migration.)

Answer (score 0):

Were you booted from Macintosh HD when you threw the music in the trash? If so, it'll be in /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user/.Trash (note that the screenshot you linked shows most of the space is taken up by .../Users/user, which fits this).

The ".Trashes" folder is only used for non-startup volumes (or, more accurately, volumes other than the one the user's home folder is on); on the startup (/home folder) volume, the trash is stored in ~/.Trash instead.

Note: since the .Trash folder is invisible, reaching it can be a little tricky. The simplest was is to navigate to the /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/user normally in the Finder, then choose Go menu > Go To Folder (or use the shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>), then enter ".Trash" as the folder to go to. You can then move its contents to your current trash (stored in /Volumes/Macintosh HD/.Trashes/youruserid/) and delete them normally.

Comment: Nope. I was booted from the SSD and the Macintosh HD was unmounted. There was stuff in the Trash from the unmounted Macintosh HD. Those items are no longer in the trash but the space was never recovered. I checked in the .Trashes folder as well as the user specific .Trash folder. I might just back everything up, format the HD and then restore. I guess that will be an ok solution if no one can come up with a better one.

Comment: Looking at the screenshot, Omnidisksweeper seems to be indicating that most of the space is taken up by /Users/user, /Applications, and  /TryingToClean.spa[truncated]. Is that last folder something you recognize, or is it possible the files got moved there (e.g. by trash it)? If not, take a look inside /Users/user with Omnidisksweeper and see if you can find anything suspicious there.

Comment: It's a folder (more specifically an image file) that I recognize. Not something moved by Trash It. :(